# Vb.Net - custom mail column in DGV

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Mery Xmas!

1. I'm trying to build a custom DGV column with one small basic enhancement: a handler for keypress and validated events. And it works. What does not work is when i try to add an image for the cell. There is something wrong somewhere in the paint event (i'm guessing).
2. This is the code i have now:

```
Namespace MailDGV
    Public Class MailColumn
        Inherits DataGridViewColumn

        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New(New MailCell())

        End Sub

        Public Overrides Property CellTemplate As DataGridViewCell
            Get
                Return MyBase.CellTemplate
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As DataGridViewCell)

                If value IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not value.[GetType]().IsAssignableFrom(GetType(MailCell)) Then
                    Throw New InvalidCastException("Nu e in formatul corect {MailColumn\CellTemplate}!")
                End If

                MyBase.CellTemplate = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Overrides Function Clone() As Object
            Dim c As MailColumn = CType(MyBase.Clone(), MailColumn)

            Return c
        End Function


    End Class

    Public Class MailCell
        Inherits DataGridViewTextBoxCell 'this was the offending line:DataGridViewCell

        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New()

        End Sub

#Region "Inherit"
        Public Overrides Function Clone() As Object
            Dim c As MailCell = CType(MyBase.Clone(), MailCell)
            Return c
        End Function

        Public Overrides Sub InitializeEditingControl(ByVal rowIndex As Integer, ByVal initialFormattedValue As Object, ByVal dataGridViewCellStyle As DataGridViewCellStyle)
            Dim ctl As MailEditingControl = TryCast(DataGridView.EditingControl, MailEditingControl)

            MyBase.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue, dataGridViewCellStyle)
            ctl.IsNewRow = CType(Me.OwningColumn, MailColumn).DataGridView.CurrentRow.IsNewRow
        End Sub

        Public Overrides ReadOnly Property EditType As Type
            Get
                Return GetType(MailEditingControl)
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Overrides Property ValueType As Type
            Get
                Return GetType(Object)
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Type)

            End Set
        End Property

        Public Overrides ReadOnly Property DefaultNewRowValue As Object
            Get
                Return "< Adaugă >"
            End Get
        End Property
#End Region

        Protected Overrides Sub Paint(graphics As Graphics, clipBounds As Rectangle, cellBounds As Rectangle, rowIndex As Integer, cellState As DataGridViewElementStates, value As Object, formattedValue As Object, errorText As String, cellStyle As DataGridViewCellStyle, advancedBorderStyle As DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle, paintParts As DataGridViewPaintParts)
            MyBase.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, cellState, value, formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, paintParts)

            Dim fnt As Font = CType(Me.OwningColumn, MailColumn).InheritedStyle.Font
            Dim textColor As Color = CType(Me.OwningColumn, MailColumn).InheritedStyle.ForeColor
            If (cellState And DataGridViewElementStates.Selected) = DataGridViewElementStates.Selected Then textColor = CType(Me.OwningColumn, MailColumn).InheritedStyle.SelectionForeColor

            If Not IsDBNull(value) Then
                graphics.DrawImage(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("mail_small"), New Rectangle(cellBounds.X + 2, CInt(cellBounds.Y + ((cellBounds.Height - My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("mail_small").Height) / 2)), Math.Min(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("mail_small").Width, 24), 16))
                graphics.DrawString(value, fnt, New SolidBrush(textColor), New PointF(cellBounds.X + 26, (cellBounds.Y + (cellBounds.Height - graphics.MeasureString(value, fnt).Height) / 2)))
            End If

        End Sub
    End Class

    Class MailEditingControl
        Inherits TextBox
        Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl

#Region "Vars"
        'The grid that owns this editing control
        Private dataGridViewControl As DataGridView
        'Stores whether the editing control's value has changed or not
        Private valueIsChanged As Boolean = False
        'Stores the row index in which the editing control resides
        Private rowIndex As Integer

        Friend IsNewRow As Boolean
#End Region

        Public Sub New()
            Me.Font = New Font(Me.Font.FontFamily, Me.Font.Size, Me.Font.Style Or FontStyle.Bold)

        End Sub

        Public Property EditingControlDataGridView As DataGridView Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlDataGridView
            Get
                Return dataGridViewControl
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As DataGridView)
                dataGridViewControl = value
            End Set

        End Property

        Public Property EditingControlFormattedValue As Object Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlFormattedValue
            Get
                Return Me.Text
            End Get

            Set(value As Object)
                Me.Text = value
            End Set

        End Property

        Public Property EditingControlRowIndex As Integer Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlRowIndex
            Get
                Return rowIndex
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Integer)
                rowIndex = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property EditingControlValueChanged As Boolean Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlValueChanged
            Get
                Return valueIsChanged
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
                valueIsChanged = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public ReadOnly Property EditingPanelCursor As Cursor Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingPanelCursor
            Get
                Return MyBase.Cursor
            End Get
        End Property

        Public ReadOnly Property RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange As Boolean Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange
            Get
                Return False
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Sub ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl(dataGridViewCellStyle As DataGridViewCellStyle) Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl
            Me.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left
        End Sub

        Public Sub PrepareEditingControlForEdit(selectAll As Boolean) Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.PrepareEditingControlForEdit
            Me.SelectionStart = Len(Me.Text)
            Me.SelectionLength = 0
        End Sub

        Private Sub MailEditingControl_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
            Dim ac As String = "@"
            If e.KeyChar <> ChrW(Keys.Back) Then
                If Asc(e.KeyChar) < 97 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 122 Then
                    If Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 46 And Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 95 Then
                        If Asc(e.KeyChar) < 48 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 57 Then
                            If ac.IndexOf(e.KeyChar) = -1 Then
                                e.Handled = True

                            Else

                                If Me.Text.Contains("@") And e.KeyChar = "@" Then
                                    e.Handled = True
                                End If

                            End If

                        End If
                    End If
                End If

            End If
        End Sub

        Private Sub MailEditingControl_Validating(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles Me.Validating
            If Not IsNothing(Me.Text) AndAlso Me.Text <> "" Then
                With New clsEmail
                    If Not .isValid(Me.Text) Then
                        If IsNewRow Then
                            dataGridViewControl.AllowUserToAddRows = False
                            dataGridViewControl.AllowUserToDeleteRows = True
                        Else
                            e.Cancel = True
                        End If
                    End If
                End With

            End If
        End Sub

        Public Function EditingControlWantsInputKey(keyData As Keys, dataGridViewWantsInputKey As Boolean) As Boolean Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlWantsInputKey
            Select Case keyData And Keys.KeyCode
                Case Keys.Left, Keys.Up, Keys.Down, Keys.Right, Keys.Home, Keys.[End], Keys.PageDown, Keys.PageUp
                    Return True
                Case Else
                    Return Not dataGridViewWantsInputKey
            End Select
        End Function

        Public Function GetEditingControlFormattedValue(context As DataGridViewDataErrorContexts) As Object Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.GetEditingControlFormattedValue
            Return EditingControlFormattedValue
        End Function


    End Class
End Namespace
```

I imagine there would be easier ways of doing this, but I'm also trying to learn how to build a custom dgv column, so it would be helpful if the answers would be on this point. Thank you :)

Comment: Does it give you an error message that you could [edit] into your question?

Comment: Ensure you have enabled [Option Strict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement). Also see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XnWgEJ1HuQs

Comment: Unfortunately there is no error. Just that the cells are painted without border and whenever i try to resize any row, the cells in my custom column get dirty and remain like that...

Comment: I found it: this "Inherits DataGridViewCell" was supposed to be this "DataGridViewTextBoxCell"

Answer (score 0):

This is what i ended up with. I'm not sure about the Validating and Validated events, but this was the only way i could think of.

```
Namespace MailDGV
Public Class MailColumn
    Inherits DataGridViewColumn

#Region "Inherit"
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New(New MailCell())

    End Sub

    Public Overrides Property CellTemplate As DataGridViewCell
        Get
            Return MyBase.CellTemplate
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As DataGridViewCell)

            If value IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not value.[GetType]().IsAssignableFrom(GetType(MailCell)) Then
                Throw New InvalidCastException("Nu e in formatul corect {MailColumn\CellTemplate}!")
            End If

            MyBase.CellTemplate = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Overrides Function Clone() As Object
        Dim c As MailColumn = CType(MyBase.Clone(), MailColumn)

        Return c
    End Function

#End Region

End Class

Public Class MailCell
    Inherits DataGridViewTextBoxCell

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()

    End Sub

#Region "Inherit"
    Public Overrides Function Clone() As Object
        Dim c As MailCell = CType(MyBase.Clone(), MailCell)
        Return c
    End Function

    Public Overrides Sub InitializeEditingControl(ByVal rowIndex As Integer, ByVal initialFormattedValue As Object, ByVal dataGridViewCellStyle As DataGridViewCellStyle)
        Dim ctl As MailEditingControl = TryCast(DataGridView.EditingControl, MailEditingControl)

        MyBase.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue, dataGridViewCellStyle)
        ctl.initValue = initialFormattedValue
    End Sub

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property EditType As Type
        Get
            Return GetType(MailEditingControl)
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ValueType As Type
        Get
            Return GetType(String)
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property DefaultNewRowValue As Object
        Get
            Return "< Adaugă >"
        End Get
    End Property
#End Region

    Protected Overrides Sub Paint(ByVal graphics As Graphics, ByVal clipBounds As Rectangle, ByVal cellBounds As Rectangle, ByVal rowIndex As Integer, ByVal cellState As DataGridViewElementStates, ByVal value As Object, ByVal formattedValue As Object, ByVal errorText As String, ByVal cellStyle As DataGridViewCellStyle, ByVal advancedBorderStyle As DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle, ByVal paintParts As DataGridViewPaintParts)
        MyBase.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, cellState, value, "", errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, paintParts)

        Dim fnt As Font = CType(Me.OwningColumn, MailColumn).InheritedStyle.Font
        Dim textColor As Color = CType(Me.OwningColumn, MailColumn).InheritedStyle.ForeColor
        If (cellState And DataGridViewElementStates.Selected) = DataGridViewElementStates.Selected Then textColor = CType(Me.OwningColumn, MailColumn).InheritedStyle.SelectionForeColor

        If Not IsDBNull(value) Then
            If Me.DataGridView.Rows(Math.Max(Me.RowIndex, 0)).IsNewRow Then
                graphics.DrawImage(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("mail_small"), New Rectangle(cellBounds.X + 2, CInt(cellBounds.Y + ((cellBounds.Height - My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("mail_small").Height) / 2)), Math.Min(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("mail_small").Width, 16), 16))
                graphics.DrawString(value, fnt, New SolidBrush(textColor), New PointF(cellBounds.X + 18, (cellBounds.Y + (cellBounds.Height - graphics.MeasureString(value, fnt).Height) / 2)))
            Else
                graphics.DrawString(value, fnt, New SolidBrush(textColor), New PointF(cellBounds.X + 2, (cellBounds.Y + (cellBounds.Height - graphics.MeasureString(value, fnt).Height) / 2)))
            End If
        Else
            MyBase.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, cellState, value, formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, paintParts)
        End If

    End Sub
End Class

Class MailEditingControl
    Inherits TextBox
    Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl

#Region "Vars"
    'The grid that owns this editing control
    Private dataGridViewControl As DataGridView
    'Stores whether the editing control's value has changed or not
    Private valueIsChanged As Boolean = False
    'Stores the row index in which the editing control resides
    Private rowIndex As Integer

    Private MailIsValid As Boolean

    Friend initValue As String

#End Region

    Public Sub New()
        Me.Font = New Font(Me.Font.FontFamily, Me.Font.Size, Me.Font.Style Or FontStyle.Bold)

    End Sub

    Public Property EditingControlDataGridView As DataGridView Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlDataGridView
        Get
            Return dataGridViewControl
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As DataGridView)
            dataGridViewControl = value
        End Set

    End Property

    Public Property EditingControlFormattedValue As Object Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlFormattedValue
        Get
            Return Me.Text
        End Get

        Set(value As Object)
            Me.Text = value
        End Set

    End Property

    Public Property EditingControlRowIndex As Integer Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlRowIndex
        Get
            Return rowIndex
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            rowIndex = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property EditingControlValueChanged As Boolean Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlValueChanged
        Get
            Return valueIsChanged
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            valueIsChanged = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property EditingPanelCursor As Cursor Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingPanelCursor
        Get
            Return MyBase.Cursor
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange As Boolean Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl(dataGridViewCellStyle As DataGridViewCellStyle) Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl
        Me.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left
    End Sub

    Public Sub PrepareEditingControlForEdit(selectAll As Boolean) Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.PrepareEditingControlForEdit
        Me.SelectionStart = Len(Me.Text)
        Me.SelectionLength = 0
    End Sub

    Private Sub MailEditingControl_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
        Dim ac As String = "@"
        If e.KeyChar <> ChrW(Keys.Back) Then
            If Asc(e.KeyChar) < 97 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 122 Then
                If Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 46 And Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 95 Then
                    If Asc(e.KeyChar) < 48 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 57 Then
                        If ac.IndexOf(e.KeyChar) = -1 Then
                            e.Handled = True

                        Else

                            If Me.Text.Contains("@") And e.KeyChar = "@" Then
                                e.Handled = True
                            End If

                        End If

                    End If
                End If
            End If

        End If
    End Sub


    Public Function EditingControlWantsInputKey(keyData As Keys, dataGridViewWantsInputKey As Boolean) As Boolean Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlWantsInputKey
        Select Case keyData And Keys.KeyCode
            Case Keys.Left, Keys.Up, Keys.Down, Keys.Right, Keys.Home, Keys.[End], Keys.PageDown, Keys.PageUp
                Return True
            Case Else
                Return Not dataGridViewWantsInputKey
        End Select
    End Function

    Public Function GetEditingControlFormattedValue(context As DataGridViewDataErrorContexts) As Object Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.GetEditingControlFormattedValue
        Return EditingControlFormattedValue
    End Function

    Private Sub MailEditingControl_Validating(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles Me.Validating
        Try
            If Not IsNothing(sender.Text) AndAlso sender.Text <> "" Then
                With New clsEmail
                    If Not .isValid(sender.Text) Then
                        MailIsValid = False
                    Else
                        MailIsValid = True
                    End If
                End With

            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            Dim msg As New ShowHtmlMessage
            msg.ShowMessage(ex)

        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub MailEditingControl_Validated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Validated
        If MailIsValid Then
            Me.EditingControlDataGridView.CurrentCell.Value = sender.text
            Me.EditingControlDataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(MailIsValid)
        Else
            Me.EditingControlDataGridView.CurrentCell.Value = initValue
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
End Namespace
```